# How do I avoid "Error creating scheduled query: The caller does not have permission" when setting up a BigQuery scheduled query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to set up a scheduled query in BigQuery through the web UI in GCP but I am getting:

```
Error creating scheduled query: The caller does not have permission
```

I am creating this query *outside* of my organisation (under another organisation), but my email address has been given bigquery.transfers.update permission within the other organisation. Previously the error message specified that I needed that permission, now it is much more generic - as above. The query runs as expected without scheduling.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to schedule queries you need to add 
`bigquery.datasets.update` also. Since you are capable to run queries in that table you wouldn't have any further problem to achieve that.

[These](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#required_permissions) are the minimum permissions required to schedule queries in BigQuery. (Assuming that you have enough permissions to get tables & dataset data)